# Want to Count Row of sheet 3 and 4 only and show count in message box

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted rows count of sheet 2 and 3 only in one message box only.

with below code i am getting count of all sheet and in different messagebox.

```
Sub FindingLastRow()


For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    MsgBox sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1 & " " & sh.Name & " " & "Trade/s"
    Next sh


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Sub last_lines()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim s As String
    
    For i = 2 To 3
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i)
            s = s & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1 & " - " & .Name & " " & "Trade/s" & vbLf
        End With
    Next i
    
    MsgBox Prompt:=s, Title:="Last lines", Buttons:=vbOKOnly
End Sub
```